# visual studio 2010 beta 2, javascript/jquery intellisense not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

has anyone experienced a similar problem? ive recently upgraded my solution to 2010 beta 2 and now i have lost javascript/jquery intellisense support, it worked fine with visual studio 2008!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [resetting Visual Studio settings](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/50857.aspx) might solve it.

Comment: Just a tip: To enable intellisense in an imported javascript file you need to put a "hint" to vs.. this comment: /// <reference path="jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js"/> on the top of the file. If this hint isn't there, intellisense will also work but it will only show basic properties and methods.

Comment: this didn't work for me, i still don't get Jquery intellisense.

Answer (score 0):

One of our developers ran into this today. We tried resetting the environment settings, monkeying with VSDOC files and a few other tricks we found with no luck.

What did solve it was dragging/dropping the jquery.js file from the solution explorer pane onto the editor pane as described on this page:

http://blog.meidianto.com/2010/05/13/vs2010-tips-7-how-to-make-jquery-intellisense-work-for-external-javascript-file/